# System.Web.HttpException: <html path> is not a valid virtual path

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

I try lots of solution that solve by others, but it still got this error:

'http:/gg:9090/Product/HtmlDetail/test.htm' is not a valid virtual path.
I want to print the content of test.htm text into my div block.
This is my code:

```
<% Response.WriteFile("http://gg:9090/Product/HtmlDetail/test.htm"); %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<% Response.WriteFile("~/HtmlDetail/test.htm"); %>
```

**EDIT:**

in codebehind:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://gg:9090/Product/HtmlDetail/test.htm");
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
string content = sr.ReadToEnd();
div1.InnerHtml = content;
```

in aspx page:

```
<div id="div1" runat="server"></div>
```

Comment: It error : Could not find a part of the path 'Y:\HtmlDetail\test.htm'.

Comment: change the path according to the page which you are executing  or try       ~/test.htm...Could not find a part of the path is caused to invalid path specification..

Comment: Thanks karthi. But I want to do is take the html file from another web site, not in my project.

Comment: <div> <% Response.WriteFile("http://gg:9090/Product/HtmlDetail/test.htm"); %></div>

Comment: gg:9090/Product/HtmlDetail/test.htm is this url correct or are you just specifying it here for an example

Comment: This block of code I write it in my view of asp.net mvc project.